# Setting width of iconContainer of StepperButton in react material-ui

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using the callemall react material-ui Stepper component to good effect but there's one thing I can't seem to do:
Within a Stepper you have Steps. Those Steps have StepButtons which can have an icon. The icon is within a span that gets the style: styles.iconContainer.

Unfortunately the width there is hardcoded to 24px which is a problem if you want to have bigger icons. Try as I might I'm not able to override the width of said container.

This leads to the following situation, I have a button with an Icon (bigger than normal) and some text underneath it. This works fine but the Icon doesn't get centered as the span containing it is too small.

Looks like this (look at the second and third Icon, they are not centered):
[image: uncentered]

If I change the hardcoded width of 24px to 100% it looks like this (much better):
[image: centered]

Unfortunately I can only achieve this if I change the code of the StepLabel component itself, something I don't want to do. The code that prepares the style looks like this:

```
var styles = {
root: {
  height: orientation === 'horizontal' ? 72 : 64,
  color: textColor,
  display: 'flex',
  alignItems: 'center',
  fontSize: 14,
  paddingLeft: 14,
  paddingRight: 14
},
icon: {
  color: iconColor,
  display: 'block',
  fontSize: 24,
  width: 24,
  height: 24
},
iconContainer: {
  display: 'flex',
  alignItems: 'center',
  paddingRight: 8,
  width: 24 -->this hardcoded thing is giving me headaches
}
```

};

So, does anyone have a suggestion on how I could override this specific style?

Source for the StepLabel Component can be found at: [GitHub | StepLabel](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/Stepper/StepLabel.js) if you need to see it within context.

Comment: Have you found a way to override the step button or label size to make it larger?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it is all hardcoded in the sourcecode.

I raised an issue at https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/4682 if you find a solution in the meantime please let us know.

Comment: This is a simple fix, but they have so many issues and PRs that's I guess it's just easier to create your own Stepper component.